# Error: Unable to resolve module `api-ecommerce`

Tags: c#, android, react-native

Im setting up a android app to connect with my wordpress woocommerce site.

when i run the setup i get a error code 500

error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `api-ecommerce` from `C:\Users\Ivo Kalu\Desktop\mstore-3.7.2\mstore-pro\src\Router.js`: Module `api-ecommerce` does not exist in the Haste module map

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1: npm install api-ecommerce
2: react-native link api-ecommerce

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn install api-ecommerce
```

Use yarn to install the package.